# Passing slices to arbitrary functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

**Short version:**

I have just read about extended slicing and have learned that one can pass a tuple of slices to `__getitem__`:

```
a[::3, 1::3]
```

Nevertheless, you cannot pass slices to arbitrary functions (Please correct me if I am wrong), hence this will fail:

```
f(::3, 1::3)
```

The somehow cumbersome workaround is calling `slice`:

```
f(slice(None, None, 3), slice(1, None, 3))
```

**1. Are there slice literals (comprehensions) like `[]` for lists, `{}` for dictionaries and sets or `()` for generators and tuples? (Maybe `<start, end, step>` or whatever)**

**2. Is it possible to pass slices to arbitrary functions in the neat slice notation?**

---

**Long version (TL;DR):**

If I want to coalesce over different slices of a list, i.e. find the first element of these slices which does not evaluate to `False`, it would be nice if I could pass the well-known and really concise slice notation to this function. Now a solution could be the following, but I am not sure if this is ill-advised:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.3

class Array(list):
    class Coalescer:
        def __init__(self, array):
            self.array = array

        def __getitem__(self, slices):
            if not isinstance(slices, tuple):
                slices = (slices,)
            for s in slices:
                for e in self.array[s]:
                    if e: return e
            return None

    @property
    def coalesce(self):
        return Array.Coalescer(self)

a = Array ([0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6])

print(a.coalesce[:]) #2
print(a.coalesce[::3]) #None
print(a.coalesce[1::3]) #3
print(a.coalesce[::3, 1::3]) #3
a [6] = 42
print(a.coalesce[::3, 1::3]) #42
```

IMHO, this is more readable than `a.coalesce(slice(None, None, 3), slice(1, None, 3))` or even `coalesce(a, slice(None, None, 3), slice(1, None, 3))`.

**3. Is this a viable option or a bad example of how not to use `__getitem__`?**

**4. Is there a PEP or other document which gives guidelines when and how to overwrite `__getitem__`, and more importantly when not and how not?**

**5. Which would be, in your estimated opinion, the most appropriate way to implement a function that coalesces over an ordered list of slices?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you could just use NumPy? Or, if you insist on rolling your own, borrow the idea of view objects.

Comment: @JanneKarila Thank you Janne. Are there literals for slices or is it possible to pass slices (in the well-known slice notation) to arbitrary functions using NumPy? Perhaps you could post an answer explaining how NumPy addresses these two topics.

Comment: You could write a `coalesce` function that is used like `coalesce(a[::3])`

Comment: No, python doesn't have slice literals outside the `[]` used to index an identifier. You can write a class that implements `__getitem__` and returns the slice, something like: `class Index:def __getitem__(self, index):return index` and then use it as `index = Index(); some_function(index[::3], index[1::3])` instead of the `slice(None, None, 3)`

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you. A pity that there aren't literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest using NumPy or pandas and creating a function that would just receive, as @JanneKarila suggested `coalesce(a[::3])`

But if you have to create an object that can be sliced and that has functions that should also implement slices I would follow the approach the Pandas library did.

1. You have a DataFrame (don't bother with names) object `df` and you can do slicing on it using `df[1:3]`
2. But if you want some special slicing then they implemented another object, that has a reference to the first one which also implements slicing and is available as an attribute of the first object `df.ix[3:5]`.

Your implementation would look something like this:

```
class SpecialSlicer(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getitem__(self, ...):
       return sefl.obj[...]

class Array(object):
    def __init__(self):
       # do your stuff
       self.ss = SpecialSlicer(self)

    def __gettitem__(self, ...):
        return ....
```

So now you can do:

```
 a = Array()
 a[3:4]
 a.ss[4:5]
```

But again, in this case, if I understood the problem correctly, I would go for a function that just receives an already sliced object.

Comment: Thank you. If I am not mistaken, your code snippet does exactly the same thing as my code in the TL;DR part of my question. If Pandas does this, I guess that doing so is a viable option and not a bad way of using getitem.

Comment: Yes it's a viable option. The only difference between your and my code is that you create the indexer object whenever the property is accessed which is in this case, I think, unnecessary.